# Load image from API using a button

Tags: json, swiftui, uiimage

In my app, the user can search for an image from a specific API and then click on a button to get that image's url. My question is how to display the image to the user?

ContentView:

```
@StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()

 var body: some View {

       // Text to display the link of the Image, when clicked on, it opens in Safari:
        Text("\(dataModel.imageURL)")
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                let url = URL(string: dataModel.imageURL)
                guard let recievedURL = url, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(recievedURL) else { return }
                UIApplication.shared.open(recievedURL)
            }

        // TextField where the user enters the search word:
        TextField("Search Images...", text: $dataModel.searchTerm)

        // After pressing this button, the DataModel fetches the data and presents the url in the text above:
        Button(action: {
            dataModel.fetchAPI()
        }, label: {
            Text("Fetch Image")
        })
    }
```

The function in DataModel() that fetches the data:

```
    @Published var imageURL = String()
    @Published var searchTerm = String()

func fetchAPI() {
        guard let url = URL(string:{The url including the searchWord}) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let recievedData = data, error == nil else {
                print("ERROR: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }
            do {
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(ImageData.self, from: recievedData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.imageURL = model.data.first?.url ?? "No URL"
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
```

When I try to create an Image from the received data the app immediately crashes of course because the data is nil. So how can I display the Image after the user presses the button the data get fetched?

Comment: You could try looking at SDWebImageSwiftUI:
https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the URL, you can initiate another network call to get the data from that URL. Then, you can create a `UIImage` from `Data` like this:

```
UIImage(data: receivedData)
```

If you add a `UIImage` property to your DataModel, you'd have something like this:

```
@Published var image : UIImage?

//after you get the data from your network call:
image = UIImage(data: receivedData)
```

Then, in your `ContentView`, you can display that image if it exists:

```
if let image = dataModel.image {
  Image(uiImage: image)
}
```

The function in your data model might look something like this to achieve this:

```
class DataModel : ObservableObject {

    //other published properties    

    @Published var image : UIImage?

    var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    func getImageFromURL(url: URL) {
        self.cancellable =
            URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
                //handle errors
            }, receiveValue: { (output) in
                self.image = UIImage(data: output.data)
            })
    }

    //your original function to get the JSON and decode it...
}
```

*Note: make sure you import Combine at the top of your file or else `AnyCancellable` won't be available*

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where would I call "getImageFromURL"? Obviously, when I click on the button I call the first function which fetches the actual url of the image and after that, I need to call this new function.

Comment: Exactly. Call it once you have the url from your first function. So after where you set self.imageUrl